# Outlook Calendar REST API Recurrence Object

Tags: php, outlook, exchange-server, recurrence, office365api

I am retrieving Calendar events from Outlook365 using their RESTful API as document here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

When the event has a recurrence, instead of showing me an RRULE like every other Calendar in the world, I get a stupid object like this:

```
[Recurrence] => Array
    (
        [Pattern] => Array
            (
                [Type] => RelativeMonthly
                [Interval] => 2
                [Month] => 0
                [DayOfMonth] => 0
                [DaysOfWeek] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Thursday
                    )

                [FirstDayOfWeek] => Sunday
                [Index] => Third
            )

        [Range] => Array
            (
                [Type] => NoEnd
                [StartDate] => 2016-08-18
                [EndDate] => 0001-01-01
                [RecurrenceTimeZone] => GMT Standard Time
                [NumberOfOccurrences] => 0
            )

    )
```

I can't find any documentation or spec on this. I need to convert this to an RRULE but I have no idea what values I might be getting and what they mean. The `[pattern][type]` in the example above is `RelativeMonthly`, which I think is what you get when the event occurs only in certain months?? the Type is `Monthly` when it occurs each month, I think..??

Is there any documentation I am missing that explains the recurrence object that is returned from the Calendar API?

Or better yet a PHP script that already parses these in to an RRULE (longshot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RecurrencePattern) for the document for the **Recurrence**. We can also use the Outlook UI of creating recurrent appointment to helpful understand the **Recurrence** object. Here is an figure for your reference:

[image]

Ant the code above is that the appointment will occur at Thursday of third week every two month.

### Update

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't really want to add appointments for every type of recurrence pattern, make a note what combination I chose and then see what I got back from the API. That link looks promising, but when I visit it I get the 404 - page not found guy sitting in the chair. Is that page working for you?

Comment: Yes, the page works well for me, I will past the content from that page for your reference. See the update.

Comment: Excellent that's great, thank you. Is there any documentation as to what's the different types mean. What the difference between `RelativeMonthly` and `AbsoluteMonthly`? And when are certain properties set, for example in the array I posted `Month` and `DayOfMonth` are zero, what would the `Type` be when those have positive integers in them? I can see this being a lot of work to convert this to an RRULE...

Comment: Based the figure and description, the `RelativeMonthly` corresponding to using `first/second/third/last week` of second line of recurrence pattern of Outlook UI. And recurrence in the code you post corresponding to `occur at Thursday of third week every two month`

Comment: Thanks for all the help.